# Preposition choice for the noun word 'secret'

Tags: prepositions

I run into this question.

> We have no secrets _____ each other.

> **A**. about   **B.** between
> **C.** to      **D.** from

My first response is B (between). After deep thought, I think C and D are more suitable. The answer shows D.

I'm kind of on the fence here. I'm wondering why D is the only answer.

Comment: IMHO, A, B and D  do make sense, and might be used in colloquial speech. However, NGRAM shows *from* is far more frequently used with *each*. This is *not* a question with 100% correct answer, so one picks the best choice.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, Why not C(to)?

Comment: C can't be the answer because "secret to st" means "secret of getting that thing" like secret to success express"secret of getting success".

Comment: Instead of "about","of" is more suitable.

Comment: If the question was "We *keep* no secrets .... each other" the answer would be more certainly "from".  I think you, @dan, have enough in the comments now to write an answer.

Comment: @JamesK - wouldn't a secret we have _between us_ be our shared secret? Does anybody actually say 'between each other'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No, probably nobody says that.  I'm fairly sure that you'd get marks for "from" in this test.  I'm just saying that it might have been better to use "keep" instead of "have".